# Different Formula for Different Record Types

Tags: formula, custom-object, formula-field, record-type

I have a custom object that has all the same fields except the value of one depends on the record type. I would imagine I could define a lengthy formula with `IF` but is there a cleaner way?

Ideally, I could have a related object and have each entry have their own formula supplied instead of predefined. Then I can use the value of this in the parent formula.

For example, if I have an `Order` object and an `Order_Type` object, I would like to have `Order_Type` have a formula field `Factor` but as input, not defined. Then I could use it in `Order` like `Order_Type__r.Factor__c * Quantity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by cleaner way. The IF() can be pretty clean / easy to implement if you print it clearly.

IF(RecordType.Name = 'RT1', 'ABC',
IF(RecordType.Name = 'RT2', 'DEF',
IF(RecordType.Name = 'RT3', 'GHI',
"")))

in my opinion, this is pretty clean.

To answer your question, you can use the CASE function as well but this will only be as 'clean' as you make it as well.

CASE(RecordType.Name,
'RT1', 'ABC',
'RT2', 'DEF',
'RT3', 'GHI',
'')

This took me a few seconds to write up. it is still unclear what the problem you are facing is.

For future questions, please refer to [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing up a question. Make sure to include a more descriptive explanation of the problem you are facing, what you have tried and what specifically you would like to know.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity! I understand I'm somewhat ambiguous, but it's one of those things where you don't know what you don't know. I attempted to articulate my desire to the best of my ability, but it seems as though that the `IF` path is the way to go.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. It is totally acceptable to ask for best practices. I see you have updated your question,  however let us know specifically what you are trying to accomplish with a **clear** example. It is still unclear to me what you are trying to do.
i.e, I have two Objects: **Order** and **OrderType__c**. An Order is a child of **OrderType**. Each **OrderType__c** has a **Factor** (percentage field) and a **Quantity** (Number) field. I would like to display the __ in the **order** object. I have tried creating a formula field ___ Is there a better practice to accomplish this?

Comment: Doing this helps contributor's give a better answer to your situation. It also helps others that are facing a similar problem use this as a resource.

(sorry to preach :) )